# Excel 2013 - combining conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I'm not very proficient when it comes to Excel formulas, so a few weeks ago I posted a question & got a great answer.  Since then, I realized there's one additional thing that would make this even better, but I have no idea how to add to the conditional formatting to make it work.

My original question is here:
[Excel 2013 - combine conditional formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/1088796/excel-2013-combine-conditional-formatting)

Additionally, here's a screenshot of what my spreadsheet looks like when I've filled in data:
[image: see screenshot here]

The cell directly to the right of the yellow date cell is the "master" revision the others cells to the right of it should match - when a number is input.  Below, any time I say "left" or "right", it's referring to the left of the date field, or to the right of the "master" revision cell.

Each cell on the left corresponds to a specific cell on the right.  When inputting YES into any cell on the left, it should turn the corresponding revision cell on the right to orange, to flag that I need to go find the label & check the revision.  This is working perfectly.

Then, when putting data into a cell on the right, there should be 2 conditions: 1) if the value doesn't match "master" revision (in the cell directly to the right of the date cell) = red (THIS WORKS), and 2) if the value entered is "N/A" or "None" (or if the value matches the "master" revision, WHICH WORKS) then don't turn the cell red.  The "N/A" or "None" part is what I don't know how to add, the cells are staying red because the content doesn't match the "master" revision cell.

If anyone can tell me how to update my conditional formatting to remove the red highlight when inputting an "N/A" or "None", I would really appreciate it.

The current conditional formulas are:

for the orange: `=AND(ISBLANK(O42),F42="YES")`

for the red: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(O42)),O42<>M42)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, just modify you're second conditional format forumal:

Therefore, this:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(O42)),O42<>M42)
```

Becomes:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(O42)),O42<>M42,O42<>"N/A",O42<>"None")
```

If you break this down to English, it reads something like this:

- Red will be applied (as per your conditional formatting)... *if O42 is not blank, and O42 is not the same as M42, and O42 is not equal to "N/A"/"None".*

You can modify this further to add more AND and OR statements within each other, if you need to add more complexities.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more condition to your And for Red, O42<>"N/A",O42<>"None" your formula will look like the following:
**=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(O42)),O42<>M42,O42<>"N/A",O42<>"None")**
The cell will turn Red when all the condition are true

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Continuing with the style of what you already have,
go add 2 new rules, Both are for specific text, one uses N/A and the other uses None for the text. Do not set any format or set the format that you want for a N/A.

Then select stop if true and make sure it is before the red format conditional. This will make it so the Red formatting rule never gets a chance to turn the cell red.